# JDOQL Any way to avoid multiple .contains() calls in the query when searching for the presence of one or more elements in a member List variable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo, jdoql

The question pretty much says it all.

If I have a class `Class A`

```
public class A {
    ...
    private List<String> keys;
    ...
}
```

And I want to select all `A` instances from the DataStore that have atleast one of a List of keys, is there a better way of doing it than this:

```
query = pm.newQuery(A.class);
query.setFilter("keys.contains(:key1) || keys.contains(:key2) || keys.contains(:key3)");
List<A> results = (List<A>)query.execute(key1, key2, key3);
```

This has not yet been implemented, so I am open to radical suggestions.

Comment: Bear in mind that even if this works (in Python, the syntax is 'WHERE keys in $1'), it does so by executing multiple queries under the covers. You'd be better off with an approach that avoids this, such as inverting the relationship, so you can fetch a list of entities by key, then look up the union of the records they reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SELECT FROM " + A.class.getName() + " WHERE keys.contains(var) && (var == :key1 || var == :key2 || var == :key3) VARIABLES java.lang.String var"

Or at least that's what we'd use with other datastores; anyones guess if Google have implemented it.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was looking for, but no idea if G implements or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's now implemented in gae so your code runs perfectly.
Here another example:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Book.class);
query.setFilter("_AuthorKeys.contains(:key1) || _AuthorKeys.contains(:key2)");
Key key1 = KeyFactory.stringToKey("xxxxxxxxxxx");
Key key2 = KeyFactory.stringToKey("yyyyyyyyyyy");
List<Book> books = (List<Book>) query.execute(key1, key2);
```

or

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Book.class);
query.setFilter("_AuthorKeys.contains(:keys)");
List<Key> keys = new LinkedList();
keys.add(KeyFactory.stringToKey("xxxxxx"));
keys.add(KeyFactory.stringToKey("yyyyyy"));
List<Book> books = (List<Book>) query.execute(keys);
```